# VS Code: staging an edit unstages other edits in the same file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When editing a file (shell script in this case) and having made two change I

- Stage one change
- Stage the other change
- The first change is now unstaged.
  Is this how git integration is supposed to work in VS Code? It seems like I used to be able to stage several changes and commit at one time (I use the git on the command line for that.)

This is on VS Code 1.33.1 on Debian Linux (Stretch/9)
Git version is 2.11.0.

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing of VSCode, but if you have a single file *F*, there are actually three "active" copies of *F* at any one time: the committed copy (which you can't change) in the current commit, the index/staging-area copy (which you can replace wholesale at any time), and the work-tree copy (which is yours to edit as you will). If you have a tool that says "take the worktree copy, make it exactly match the HEAD copy, make one change to it, and copy that to the index / staging area", that would produce the behavior you see: you'd have to *commit* that one change in this case.

Comment: If there are only two changes in the work-tree copy, just let it put both into the index / staging-area copy (by copying the work-tree copy to the index copy) if you want to commit both at the same time. But if you have THREE changes to the work-tree copy, now you have a problem if your tool will only let you stage one of them (i.e., will only take the HEAD copy and apply one of the three changes before re-copying to the index / stage).

Comment: If you're willing to use raw Git, instead of VSCode, `git add -p` and `git reset -p` work the way you'd like.

Comment: More than willing to use `git` on the command line, but I was not familiar with the capability to select specific edits to commit (or revert.) It was nice to find that in VSCode but not so nice when it didn't work as I thought it did before. I also somehow managed to get it to undo some commits and I don't know how that happened. I guess I'll stick with `git ...` from now on. (And/or file a bug report.)